# SetWindowsHookEx with WH_KEYBOARD doesn't work for me, what do I wrong?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, console, keyboard-hook

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x501
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

HHOOK hKeyboardHook = 0;
LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardCallback(int code,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam) {  
  cout << "a key was pressed" << endl;
  ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open ("hookcheck.txt", ios::ate | ios::app);
  myfile << "a key was pressed\n";
  myfile.close();
  return CallNextHookEx(hKeyboardHook,code,wParam,lParam);
}

int main() {

  HWND consoleWindow = GetConsoleWindow();
  HINSTANCE hInstCons = (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong( consoleWindow, GWL_HINSTANCE );
  hKeyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx( WH_KEYBOARD, (HOOKPROC)KeyboardCallback, (HINSTANCE)consoleWindow, GetCurrentThreadId());

  MessageBox(NULL, "It is keyboard time!", "Let's Go", MB_OK);

}
```

This code on every key press while the loop is going should print message on console and create a file, but nothing is happening. What do I wrong ?

Comment: SetWindowsHookEx hooks Windows messages.  A console app doesn't use messages.  You'll have to write a native windows app that pumps a message loop.

Comment: By the way, Windows console does provide low-level input APIs, you should use them instead of using hooks.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: That's interesting, could you give me link to manual, im not quite sure about which api are you talking and I was searching for this many days.

Comment: Start from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682010.aspx).

Comment: [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685035.aspx) page in particular should be relevant to your aim.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I will quote from [another topic](http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/spy-plus-plus-console-application-help-25981632.html):

> Console windows are handled entirely by CSRSS, which is a system
>   process. Installing a hook into a process means injecting your DLL
>   into it. Since CSRSS is so important (it's vital for running of the
>   system, and code within runs as LocalSystem, which is the local
>   super-admin user), you're not allowed to inject code into it. So you
>   can't hook any of its windows.

There are no real window messages taking place in your simple console application, so your hook does not have to be called, and in your case you are not even injecting your hook but using thread mode hook only. Per MSDN documentation it is called when messages are about to be processed:

> An application-defined or library-defined callback function used with
>   the SetWindowsHookEx function. The system calls this function whenever
>   an application calls the GetMessage or PeekMessage function and there
>   is a keyboard message (WM_KEYUP or WM_KEYDOWN) to be processed.

Now let me show you what you can do to start receiving calls on your hook:

```
MessageBox(NULL, _T("It is keyboard time!"), _T("Let's Go"), MB_OK);

//for(int i=0; i<=10; i++) {
//  cout << i << endl;
//  Sleep(1000);
//}
```

Do `MessageBox` and before closing it start typing - you will start getting hook calls.

Comment: If I understand what text that you cited means, `SetWindowsHookEx` doesn't work with console apps, right ? I updated my code in question and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Works for me. Make sure your message box window is in foreground, but don't press button to close it. Type something there. This generates keyboard messages in the thread where you installed the hook. Your hook will be called.

Comment: Sorry, I do not what I'm doing wrong here but no events are showing for me. (I use gcc 4.7.0 mingw)

Comment: Most likely you are typing with no message box window in foreground, and keyboard input is not routed to the window and thread of interest.

Comment: No, I tried to do it both ways, that is with window in foreground and background mode. When message box in is in foreground I god sound on every keypress but nothing is shown on the console.

Comment: I am not quite sure if this is going to be helpful, but this is my source and binary http://www.alax.info/trac/public/browser/trunk/Utilities/ConsoleKeyboardHook Also, you might want to use `Spy++` tool to check what messages occur within your process.

Comment: Your binary also doesn't work as expected. That is it runs without any error but it also doesn't react on keypresses just identically as code compiled by me. Maybe this is a windows issue, I use XP SP3.

Comment: This is because you don't do checking per Scott Langham's suggestion. You don't have the hook installed in XP, because in XP `GetWindowLong` returns non-NULL result and you have to have NULL there (see updated code).

Comment: I am doing C programming, I have used `ShowWindow(hwnd, FALSE)` for my console window, and `SetWindowsHookEx()` does not work when I do that. Is it because my program becomes a background process?

Comment: I put `ShowWindow()` function right before my `GetMessage()` function loop for the program to keep going

Answer (score 1):

Read the documentation for SetWindowsHookEx. Is it working, it will return NULL if it fails and GetLastError() can be called to get an error code to help diagnose what is wrong.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: `GetLastError()` returns `0`. - Where can I find what it means ?

Comment: That means it succeeded :)  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: And that is true. There something strange going on, code compiles without error and there is no error showing anywhere in the code, just callback doesn't initialize.

Answer (score 1):

[`Sleep(1000)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) suspends the execution of the current thread until the time-out interval elapses. It means that your program is not actually running (ie. processing messages) during this sleep.

You need to use a different kind of command, that will keep the message loop running. The simplest thing would be to wait for user input

```
while(true)
   std::cin.get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a dll that hooked the keyboard and in there I used the [`DllMain`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)function to retrieve a `HINSTANCE` that can be used in `SetWindowsHookEx`.

Next to that I also used 0 as the threadid so all threads get hooked.

Perhaps you could try a similar tactic as well.