# Hide windows console if minimized

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have a Qt based console application, that has to be located on the Windows System Tray (aka Notification Area).

The question: how can I hide the console window instead of minimizing it if the user clicks on "minimize" icon? I know the ShowWindow method, but as I guess, I have to call it asynchronously.

Comment: Find the window handle of the console window and hide it

Comment: The program will hide itself (its window) or other program will hide it?

Answer (score -2):

You need to obtain the `HWND` window handle of the Console window, then you can use `ShowWindow` to show or hide it in the usual way.

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683175(v=vs.85).aspx

The question is when do you do this? You need to know when the window is minimised in order to know whether to hide it.

You could check this periodically, but you should be careful to ensure you are not preventing laptops etc. from sleeping by doing so.

Alternatively you could install a message hook, or subclass the window, to recieve immediate notifications.

Subclassing the window is probably the best method.

Comment: Hi, what could be the base class and which methods should be overridden in this case?

Comment: @moravas, that's not how Window Subclassing works. This technology has a history which dates from 1985, before C++ was in common use. You need to look up "window subclassing".

Comment: The console window is not your average window. It is owned by the CSRSS system process and [cannot easily be subclassed](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13371644/1889329).

Comment: Subclassing is far from the best option, it's not an option at all

Comment: @IInspectable, that answer is out of date. Te console window is owned by conhost.exe and runs in the current user context. Nothing prevents you using a hook, and subclassing can be done once one has injected the DLL containing the code.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, why do you say that?

Comment: The console window is no longer owned by CSRSS since Windows 6.1 (*"Windows 7"*). Since Windows Vista is still officially supported, the answer is anything but out of date. A solution for Windows 7 and above would be to set a [WinEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373889.aspx) hook. Subclassing, polling, or a message hook aren't appropriate solutions.